# qgis2web export categorized renderer symbology

Tags: qgis, leaflet, qgis2web, categorized-renderer

I'm trying to export my QGIS (2.14.5) categorized renderer symbology to a leaflet project with qgis2web (1.19.0).

My example QGIS project looks like this:

[image]

The resulting (preview, respectivly) leaflet looks like shown below. Note that the legend shows categories, but not the map:

[image]

qgis2web help mentions only that in leaflet only the first symbol layer is displayed, but that is not the issue in this case, me thinks.

Do I miss something, or do I something wrong?

Comment: Can you upload your layer and project?

Comment: @Tom Chadwin: solved this for me, i used an integer field for categorization wich fails. categorization seems to work only based on text fields, can you confirm this? I'm going to post this as an answer...

Comment: but beware ;-) I ran into another issue concerning categorization and svg markes, which i'm going to post in another question...

Comment: If you are right, it's a bug. I'll have a look.

Comment: And categorized SVGs don't work, no (see https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/262). I'm working on it at the moment (see https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/332).

Comment: ok, in this case this is obsolete? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218674/qgis2web-categorized-renderer-symbology-with-svg-markers-issue

Comment: Only if I succeed...