# qgis2web categorized renderer symbology with svg markers issue

Tags: qgis, leaflet, svg, qgis2web, categorized-renderer

In a simple QGIS (2.14.5LTR) project I've set up categorized renderer symbology for a small shapefile which looks like this:

[image]

Categorization is based on a text field, cp. my comment on [qgis2web export categorized renderer symbology](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218551/qgis2web-export-categorized-renderer-symbology)

Exporting this to leaflet with qgis2web (1.19.0) results in

[image]

In my opinion this is not an svg issue, because with single symbol renderers the layer symbology looks absolutely fine in the leaflet project, as proven by the screenshot below:

[image]

[image]

svg symbols are from https://openclipart.org/

The svg files in this case reside in the same folder as the shapefile and the qgis project.

The svg files, shapefile and the project can be obtained here: https://1drv.ms/f/s!AoRm0zIUU8Gdp1e975aOcc9Ksrkx

What could be my problem?

Comment: Mods, please reopen this question. Categorized/graduated renderers do not work with SVGs in Leaflet exports from qgis2web. However, it is under development (see github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/332).

Comment: Please try this with qgis2web v2 or later. Categorized/graduated SVGs are now supported in Leaflet exports.